# Translate Savitzky-Golay function from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, translate, data-processing

I'm trying to translate this Savitzky-Golay function from Matlab to R. However it doesn't work in R. How to make the R function work?

x example can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5AOSYBy_josMUgtRi1wLW4tZEE

Function inputs are:

- x (m x n) data to process
- width (1 x 1) number of points
- order (1 x 1) polynomial order
- deriv (1 x 1) derivative order

Function output is:

- xsg (m x n) processed data

Atacched are examples from Matlab and R:

---MATLAB---

```
function [xsg]= savgol(x,width,order,deriv)
[m,n]=size(x);
w=max( 3, 1+2*round((width-1)/2) );
o=min([max(0,round(order)),5,w-1]);
d=min(max(0,round(deriv)),o);
p=(w-1)/2;
xc=((-p:p)'*ones(1,1+o)).^(ones(size(1:w))'*(0:o));
we=xc\eye(w);
b=prod(ones(d,1)*[1:o+1-d]+[0:d-1]'*ones(1,o+1-d,1),1);
di=spdiags(ones(n,1)*we(d+1,:)*b(1),p:-1:-p,n,n);
w1=diag(b)*we(d+1:o+1,:);
di(1:w,1:p+1)=[xc(1:p+1,1:1+o-d)*w1]'; 
di(n-w+1:n,n-p:n)=[xc(p+1:w,1:1+o-d)*w1]';
xsg=x*di;

plot(xsg')
```

---R---

```
savgol=function(x,width,order,deriv)
{
  m=nrow(x)
  n=ncol(x)
  w=max(3,1+2*round((width-1)/2) )
  o=min(c(max(0,round(order)),5,w-1))
  d=min(max(0,round(deriv)),o)
  p=(w-1)/2
  xc=((-p:p)%*%matrix(1,1,1+o))^(t(matrix(1,1,w))%*%(0:o))
  we=qr.solve(xc,diag(w))
  b=apply((matrix(1,d,1)%*%matrix(1:(o+1-d),1,(o+1-d))+t(matrix(0:(d-1),1,(d)))%*%matrix(1,1,o+1-d)),2,prod)
  gg=matrix(1,n,1)%*%we[(d+1),]*b[1]
  library(Matrix)
  di=sparseMatrix(i=1:n,j=1:n,x=gg)
  w1=diag(b,nrow=length(b))%*%we[(d+1):(o+1),]
  di[1:w,1:(p+1)]=t(xc[1:(p+1),1:(1+o-d)]%*%w1)
  di[(n-w+1):n,(n-p):n]=t(xc[(p+1):w,1:(1+o-d)]%*%w1)
  xsg=x%*%di
    }

matplot(t(xsg),type='l')
```

Obtained plots to xsg:
[image]

Comment: Posing a problem in two different languages in the form of a code-only comparison means you are restricting your audience to facile users of both languages. You need to include comments in each code segment that adeauately describes the particular goals and expectations of each line of code. (Spaces would improve readability.)

Comment: `install.packages("sos", dep = TRUE); findFn("Savitzky-Golay")`

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't the round behaviour in R different from MatLab? 1.5 is perhaps rounded to 2, while 0.5 is rounded to 0 in R?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in R by:

```
savgol=function(x,width,order,deriv)
{
  ##insert spdiags function
  spdiags <-function (arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4){
    B <- arg1 
    if (is.matrix(arg2))
      d <- matrix(arg2,dim(arg2)[1]*dim(arg2)[2],1)
    else
      d <- arg2
    p <- length(d) 
    A <- sparseMatrix(i = 1:arg3, j = 1:arg3, x = 0, dims= c(arg3,arg4))
    m <- dim(A)[1] 
    n <- dim(A)[2] 
    len<-matrix(0,p+1,1)
    for (k in 1:p)
      len[k+1] <- len[k]+length(max(1,1-d[k]):min(m,n-d[k])) 
    a <- matrix(0, len[p+1],3) 
    for (k in 1:p)
    {
      i <- t(max(1,1-d[k]):min(m,n-d[k])) 
      a[(len[k]+1):len[k+1],] <- c(i, i+d[k], B[(i+(m>=n)*d[k]),k]) 
    }
    res1 <- sparseMatrix(i = a[,1], j = a[,2], x = a[,3], dims = c(m,n)) 
    return (res1)
  }
  ##end spdiags function

  m=nrow(x)
  n=ncol(x)
  w=max(3,1+2*round((width-1)/2) )
  o=min(c(max(0,round(order)),5,w-1))
  d=min(max(0,round(deriv)),o)
  p=(w-1)/2
  xc=((-p:p)%*%matrix(1,1,1+o))^(t(matrix(1,1,w))%*%(0:o))
  we=qr.solve(xc,diag(w))
    options(warn=-1)
  b=apply((matrix(1,d,1)%*%matrix(1:(o+1-d),1,(o+1-d))+t(matrix(0:(d-1),1,(d)))%*%matrix(1,1,o+1-d)),2,prod)
  gg=matrix(1,n,1)%*%we[(d+1),]*b[1]
    library(Matrix)
  di=spdiags(gg,p:(-p),n,n)
    options(warn=0)
  w1=diag(b,nrow=length(b))%*%we[(d+1):(o+1),]
  di[1:w,1:(p+1)]=t(xc[1:(p+1),1:(1+o-d)]%*%w1)
  di[(n-w+1):n,(n-p):n]=t(xc[(p+1):w,1:(1+o-d)]%*%w1)
  result=x%*%di
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a complete answer, but look at round:

---matlab---
Y = round(X) rounds each element of X to the nearest integer. In the case of a tie, where an element has a fractional part of exactly 0.5, the round function rounds away from zero to the integer with larger magnitude.

---R---
 Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’.

round(0.5) will result in 0 on R and 1 on matlab